# loop in dynamically updated array not working

Tags: javascript

Here is a simple javascript code that adds unique data from one array to another.

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 2]
var dump = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (dump.length == 0) {
        dump.push(data[i])
    } else {
        for (var a = 0; a < dump.length; a++) {
            if (dump[a] != data[i]) {
                if (a >= dump.length) {
                    dump.push(data[i])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I only get 1 item from the data array : [1] instead of [1,2,3]

Comment: Use pencil and paper to work your way through that algorithm and you'll see that `(a >= dump.length)` ain't ever going to be true.

Comment: Answer is not the only key, but approach is important. So I suggest you to put console.log statement and just debug it because it looks like you are missing something (in terms of programming logic).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/2609085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's becuase this line

```
if (a >= dump.length) {
    dump.push(data[i])
}
```

You pushed data when a is greater then or equal to dump.length

but in your loop

```
a < dump.length
```

It won't make it there

Try like this

```
for (var a = 0; a < dump.length; a++) {
    if (dump[a] == data[i]) { // when found break there
        break;
    }
}
if (a == dump.length) // if nothing found loop will be fully executed
    dump.push(data[i]);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bprqhr9k/)

Comment: I wanted to push the data item into the dump array only when all the dump item is checked so a >= dump.length is used. I suppose a will be incremented by 1 greater than dump.length at the end of loop (a++)

Comment: check my fiddle @RameshKhadka